# Kubuntu shuts down after entering sleep mode

Tags: boot, kernel, kubuntu, asus

When my Asus Tuf fa506qm comes back from sleep mode - all keys on keyboard trigger opening "Shut down menu".
My version of kubuntu is 21.04 and kernel 5.13.8

Can anyone help me with this issue?